# NSolve returns empty {}

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following problem I'm trying to solve,

```
B11 = 3.2604*10^9;
B12 = 9.1107*10^4;
NSolve[{2 == 0.01 N1 (B11 y1 + 2 B12 y1^2), 
  1 == 0.01 N1 (B11 y1 + B12 y1^2)}, {y1, N1}]
```

However, `NSolve` simply returns `{}` instead of an actual solution. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Because it doesn't have a solution.

Comment: It appears that one equation is just the other equation multiplied by a constant. There will not be a unique solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see that the two equations represent parallel lines. Solve for `y` from each, and treat `N1` as `x`

```
ClearAll[x,y]
B11=3.2604*10^9;
B12=9.1107*10^4;
f1[x_,y_]:=2-0.01 x(B11 y+2 B12 y^2);
f2[x_,y_]:=1-0.01 x (B11 y+B12 y^2);
y1=y/.First@Solve[Rationalize@f1[x,y]==0,y]
y2=y/.First@Solve[Rationalize@f2[x,y]==0,y]
Plot[{y1,y2},{x,0,1},PlotStyle->{Red,Blue},
  PlotLegends->{"First equation","second equation"},AxesLabel->{"N1","y1"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No solution, since lines are parallel.

Comment: Thank you for this, I see I made a mistake in the second equation where it shouldn't have had an `N1` term in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can see why it fails to have a solution using Reduce.

```
Reduce[{200 == n1 (b11 y1 + 2 b12 y1^2), 100 == n1 (b11 y1 + b12 y1^2)}, 
       {y1, n1, b11, b12}]

b11 == 0 && n1 y1 != 0 && b12 == 100/(n1 y1^2)
```

So it will only have solutions for b11=0. `Solve` gives pretty much the same answer.

Comment: Thank you for this, I see I made a mistake in the second equation where it shouldn't have had an `N1` term in it.